# Solving Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null using .on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I've gotten the error:

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

and I've been having a look at the other answers on stackoverflow and a lot of them solve by using `$(document).ready` and although this fixes my issue it's not very efficient in my case as the time the page takes to load the dom can be very slow on occasion (+7 seconds) and I would rather that as soon as the id is available, I can then use it.

Is there a way for me to do this? I've been looking as `.on()` to try to see if the id exists but not sure if it can be used this way as the way i'm using it currently means that the method is never used.

The javascript file in included in the head with the id in a jsp further down.

Using `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        updateContainerCount();
        function updateContainerCount() {
            var countElement = document.getElementById("countElement");
            if (count > 0) {
                countElement.innerHTML += ' (' + count + ')';
            }
        }
});
```

Using `.on()` with something like:

```
$('#countElement').on("load", function() {
        updateContainerCount();
        function updateContainerCount() {
            var countElement = document.getElementById("countElement");
            if (count > 0) {
                countElement.innerHTML += ' (' + count + ')';
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: The only way to do it as soon as the div is drawn on the page is to put your javascript right below the `div`. `$(document).ready` would be ideal as you don't want to clutter your HTML with javascript. Also, an element doesn't have a load event.

Comment: Count is a global variable, in my code it's _this.count so it can access it, only occasionally will it return with the null error.

Comment: About the load, that's what i thought but it was suggested to me. Do you think that document.ready is the only way to do it or is there some way to grab the id as soon as that part of the page is loaded?

Comment: That would work however wouldn't that be even slower than $(document).ready as doesn't window.onload load everything including images etc? As i understand is document.ready just loads the code ie html and javascript (please correct me if i'm wrong!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly manipulate with DOM element as long as you are sure that is has been loaded.

For example, you can put a part of your code right after the HTML declaration:

```
<div id="countElement"></div>
<script>
    var countElement = document.getElementById("countElement");
    if (count > 0) {
        countElement.innerHTML += ' (' + count + ')';
    }
</script>
```

I am pretty sure that it is not considered to be a good practice, but sometimes I use this approach in my projects - in places where it is **really** important to execute script right after element DOM loading, without waiting for document to be loaded.

*P.S.* It looks like you probably can set this HTML on back-end. If yes, then it is definitely better to generate it server-side.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not able to do that as the code is in a file with other javascript and relies on other variables in the file!

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing body of function then no need to call it from same place in document.ready, i think you have to call it like following code

first write your document.ready and only call function from there don't write function body as follows

```
$('#countElement').on("load", function() {
    updateContainerCount();
 });
```

then write function body outside of document.ready block

```
function updateContainerCount() {
        var countElement = document.getElementById("countElement");
        if (count > 0) {
            countElement.innerHTML += ' (' + count + ')';
        }
    }
```

may be this will help you

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, it's still not being accessed but it does look better! thanks